# Using classes instead of IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have two divs in my parent class, one of which is found by `$(this).parent('div').next('.deal-rolldown').show();` the other, `$(this).parent('div').next('.client-rolldown').show();` does not find what appears to by syntactically equal.

In WordPress I iterate an (unknown) number of posts, each has 2 buttons to reveal more content. Up to now I have run a document ready function in each iteration to address each reveal by IDs but this is inefficient.

So I am trying to write a function using classes. Here's the JavaScript

```
$('.deal-link').click(function() {
    $('.deal-rolldown').hide(); // hide all 
    $('.client-rolldown').hide(); // hide all 
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.deal-rolldown').show();
    }
});

$('.client-link').click(function() {
    $('.client-rolldown').hide(); // hide all 
    $('.deal-rolldown').hide(); // hide all 
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.client-rolldown').show();
    }
});
```

Which is operating on this HTML

```
<div class="company">
    <div class="company-inner">
        <h2>Company 1 </h2> Company 1 Summary
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deal-link">Deal summary</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="client-link">Client review</a>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="deal-rolldown">
    Company 1 reveal 1 content
</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="client-rolldown">
    Company 1 reveal 2 content
</div>

<div class="company">
    <div class="company-inner">
        <h2>Company 2 </h2> Company 2 Summary
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deal-link">Deal summary</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="client-link">Client review</a>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="deal-rolldown">
    Company 2 reveal 1 content
</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="client-rolldown">
    Company 2 reveal 2 content
</div>
```

The `addClass('active')` works fine so I know I am getting the right button, but the `next()` function does nothing. No errors. How can I select the appropriate reveal from each button?

Edit following closure: this is a different question to the one marked as duplicate.

Comment: $(this).next('.deal-rolldown').show(); has an issue......next works when they are at the same level...but deal link is not at the same level as deal-rolldown

Comment: you should probably do  $(this).parent('div').next('.deal-rolldown').show();

Comment: shouldn't the title be edited though? because ultimately the question is not about efficiency.

Comment: OK, although I am achieving this result successfully at present by running separate document ready functions with IDs within each div , this is an attempt to make my code more efficient

Comment: The way to address the first reveal was, as pointed out below `$(this).parent().next().show();` the qualifiers being unnecessary. the way to find the second reveal is `$(this).parent().next().next().show();`. As may seem obvious these 2 divs have to be immediately after the parent div and have no intervening tags at all. I do find this a little clumsy but without using IDs, seems the only way to target the desired DIVs

Comment: I've voted to re-open this question, but downvoted, as people who clean up duplicates on _Stack Overflow_ are anything but bullies. There is a _lot_ of unsung volunteer work on this site, and in 1% of those cases, people get it wrong. I'll ask a moderator to look at your comment.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, instead of doing

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

You can use `$(this).toggleClass('active');`

Your problem is that `next()` returns the immediately following sibling, and `.deal-rolldown` is not a sibling of your `.deal-link` element.

What you want to do is

```
$(this).parent('div').next('.deal-rolldown').show();
```

Comment: This is working for the first reveal. It is not finding the second one, ie `$(this).parent('div').next('.client-rolldown').show();` doesn't work. (changing it to .deal-dropdown does so my syntax would appear to be correct.

Comment: Sure it depends on what you want to show, from your example it seemed to me you want to show client-rolldown

Comment: From playing around it seems like this; `$(this).parent().next().show();`  has exactly the same result as `$(this).parent('div').next('.deal-rolldown').show();` and that it will only find the next tag - ie put `<p></p> `before  `<div class='deal-rolldown'>` and it no longer works. This seems to contradict the jQuery documentation ??

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` function gets the immediately following sibling that matches the selector. The div with class `'.deal-rolldown'` is NOT a sibling of the `'.client-link'` or `'.deal-link'` links. I would suggest using `.closest('.deal-rolldown')` instead of `.next()` which will find the closest matching element by traversing up through the current item's ancestors.

Comment: This will not work because you will not find any `.deal-rolldown` during traversing up, look at the OPs html